# Android check user logged in before, else start login activity

Tags: android, authentication

I want the login activity to start when the user starts the app but has not logged in before. If a successful login has been completed before, the app will skip the login page and move to MainMenu.java.
What I have now is:

```
    public class Login extends Activity implements OnClickListener, TaskCompleteCallback{

     first_time_check();

...
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.configure);

    ...}

private boolean first_time_check() {    
    String first = mPreferences.getString("first", null);
        if((first == null)){
            Intent i = new Intent(Login.this, MainMenu.class);
             startActivity(i);
        }
        return false;
    }

...
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mPreferences.edit();
        editor.putString("first", value);
    ...

        editor.commit();        

        // Close the activity
        Intent i = new Intent(Login.this, MainMenu.class);
         startActivity(i);
    }
```

But I get FCs'. Is something wrong with how I implemented SharedPreferences?

Comment: Is your 'first_time_check()' inside your onCreate() or did you forget to add the close of the onCreate() in your code shown above? Also within what function is the code you have shown commit() etc.?

Comment: I put it after the onCreate. If I put it inside, I get a ton of errors. Am I supposed to?

Comment: No. But your code shown above doesn't seem to reflect that.

Comment: apologies for that, I have edited the code

Comment: So where are you  calling 'first_time_check()' from (doesnt seem to be within onCreate())?

Comment: if I can't call it from onCreate(), how do I call it?

Comment: Unrelated: in the edit queue, I came across a question that you voted on in triage. You made the wrong choice there. Please: study the help for triage really carefully, and avoid putting items into the edit queue that don't belong there. Please understand that your votes have consequences! I am specifically talking about https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/20908294. That should have been closed as unclear/or no MCVE. Only the OP can reasonably edit it!
Feel free to drop me a comment in case you have further questions or feedback for me.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your code just never calls that `first_time_check()`, thus the automatic forward in case of a returning user does not work.

You could in `onCreate()` do

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    first_time_check();

    setContentView(R.layout.configure);

    ...}
```

So for a new user, `first_time_check()` would forward him to the login page, otherwise
the current layout would be shown and he could continue on this page.

Comment: That makes sense. But after implementing your solution, I get FC. Is there something wrong with how I used sharedpreferences?

Comment: OK works now. I placed first_time_check() after the call for mPreferences. Thank you so much!

Comment: @bernlim You put it after `mPreferences`, that's ok. But both are before calling `setContentView()`, right?

Answer (score 5):

You are using shared preferences. That is good.

There is a small example given in this link. That will probably solve the problem.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html

Basically, I'm not seeing you read the stored value. You are storing it and then committing it. But there is no code where you are reading it. Only when you read it, you can decide which activity must be launched. You have to call first_time_check() to solve this.

Hope I was able to help you.

Answer (score 1):

You could save the log in details in onSaveInstanceState() method and then restore it when your activity restarts. For example inside onRestore().

Answer (score 1):

This can be done in two ways. One is storing them in a global variables and second is storing the data in shared preferences. see [this](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/08/android-session-management-using-shared-preferences/) example.