# how do i change the landing page of the app after the user has signed in

Tags: android, authentication

i have created android app that require users to enter their phone numbers when they first use the app, now i am storing that info using SQL lite.the problem is every time they open the app it requires their phone number, and I want the app to just automatically login without asking for the phone number again, kind of like whats app.

Answer (score 0):

Its not about landing page change. The activity which has  a category "LAUNCHER" in manifest file always opens first. In that Activity .java file , You can make a check , whether the value for user is available in sqlite or not. if available perform intent to next page .. Check this link too ......[Android check user logged in before, else start login activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6718514/android-check-user-logged-in-before-else-start-login-activity)

Answer (score 0):

Either set a splash activity or another blank activity as your initial activity.
        Then store a boolean in your app's shared preference to identify whether the application
        is loading first time or not. Based on that boolean value, move to phone number entry screen or
        your desired screen.

Comment: thank you guys, if i succeed i will tell u, if i have any questions i will ask. you the best

Answer (score 0):

In your "login" activity you should look for the number in the db, if it is there, you open a new activity, if not, you ask the user. You can use setVisibility(int) in your "ask" views to not show them while looking in the db, and then, if you don't find the number, you show them.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use [sharedPrefrences](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html) where you can store whether user has stored his number.
When user open the app for the first time and enter his number, then store value in sharedprefrences.

```
    SharedPreferences sharedpreferences; 
    sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences("prefrence", Context.MODE_PRIVATE); 

   SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
   editor.putString("value", "selected"); editor.commit();
```

When user open the app, Splash screen will check the value in sharedprefrences. If user already had put his number then he will be re-directed to home screen rather than phone number screen.

**Splash Screen:**

```
Context mContext;
// Splash screen timer
private static int SPLASH_TIME_OUT = 3000;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);
    mContext = SplashScreen.this;


    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {


          /*Showing splash screen with a timer. This will be useful when you
          want to show case your app logo / company*/


        @Override
        public void run() {
            // This method will be executed once the timer is over
            // Start your app main activity

            SharedPreferences shared = getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
            String value = (shared.getString("value", ""));

            if(value!=null && !value.equals("")){
            /*Re-Direct to Home Screen after Login*/
                Intent intent = new Intent(mContext,MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
            else{
                Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, LoginActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
            // close this activity
            finish();
        }
    }, SPLASH_TIME_OUT);
}
```