# How to check login in android?

Tags: android, activity-finish

In my project, There is a `splashActivity` then `LoginActivity` and on click `社交账号登录` it takes to `SocialCountLoginActivity`. If someone click on QQ login and if login get success then `MainActivity` starts. At that time I am finishing the `LoginActivity` and `SocialCountLoginActivity`.On restart application it's taking to `LoginAcivity` instead of `MainActivity`. What should I do to start `MainAcivity` directly after successful login?

The following is my screenshot:

[image]

The folowing is my socialcountloginactivity part code:

```
private class  QQUIListener implements IUiListener{

    @Override
    public void onComplete(Object response) {
        //Login sucess
        //finish();
        JSONObject object = (JSONObject) response;
        initOpenidAndToken(object);
        getUserInfo();
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(UiError uiError) {
        //Login fail
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancel() {
        //Cancle Login
    }
}
```

The following is mainactivity code:

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // finish activity
    ActivityManagerUtil.finishSomeOneActivity(SocialAccountLoginActivity.class);
    ActivityManagerUtil.finishSomeOneActivity(LoginActivity.class);
```

}

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android check user logged in before, else start login activity](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6718514/android-check-user-logged-in-before-else-start-login-activity)

Answer (score 0):

Use shared preferences to store login details and check when your application starts. If there is some detail stored then start your main activity else navigate to login activity. If your are very new to android development then go through some session management tutorials you will get better understanding: 
Like:- http://www.androidhive.info/2012/08/android-session-management-using-shared-preferences/
 - https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_session_management.htm

Comment: I'm so sorry , perhaps I describe the problem isn't clear . Please look my screenshot , and when I click the `登录` , it doesn't directly take to mainactivity but takes to `socialcountloginactivity` , I want I click the `登录` and take to `mainactivity` directly

Comment: Yes at that button you need to check for login.

Comment: It's third login ,  just like you use your `fackbook` or `google` account login some else app , so I can't do that

Comment: no problem but you need to store third login details in your app so that you can check if user is logged In or  not.

Comment: Thanks for your time , it's my fault , and I know